# What is the verb for making objects on a plate jump up and down?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

A plate contains some objects of variety shapes. These objects could be dice or any stones.

You hold the plate with your hands and rotate your wrists up and down and thus make the plate moves up and down accordingly, which make the objects jump up and down.

DO you say "**I am tossing the objects in the plate**"?

Comment: [various shapes or a variety of shapes].

Comment: Tom, bounce is for resilient objects: bounce a baby on your knee, bounce a ball on the floor. Bear in mind that if the objects are not "bouncible", resilient, you probably will not be able to keep up the movement as they will fall off the plate.

Comment: If they do not go very high, you can say jiggle the objects on a plate. Hard objects cannot go up and down in the air off a plate!

Comment: Upvoted for the pictures!

Comment: Looking at your diagram, I immediately thought of the way that fried rice is made. If that's the context, then there is almost certainly a *specialized term* that refers only to this motion while cooking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am jiggling the objects on the plate:

Free Dictionary

> **verb (used with or without object), **jig·gled, jig·gling.**
> **to move up and down** or to and fro with short, quick jerks. noun a jiggling movement.**

**[jiggle](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/jiggle)**

You can only bounce softish objects on a plate, like a rubber ball. Not a hard object.

Hard objects such as stones and die cannot be bounced on a plate. They can be jiggled on a plate.

Comment: So, can we use "to rock"? what are the differences between "to jiggle" and  "to rock"? It seems like "to rock" doesn't mean to move up and down but both "to jiggle" and  "to rock"mean to move from side to side. "to rock" seems more gentle while "to jiggle" seems quick and short.

Comment: @Tom Just so you don't get a mistaken idea from this answer, hard objects are quite capable of bouncing away from each other. If you throw a pebble at a brick wall, the pebble will bounce back. If you fire a bullet at a metal wall at the right angle, the bullet will bounce away from it. Similarly, if you hit a rock with a plate (and assuming the plate doesn't simply break), the rock *will* bounce away. Repeatedly bouncing a rock with a plate wouldn't produce results nearly as rewarding as bouncing a ball with a plate, nonetheless it would still bounce to some degree.

Comment: Jason, if you throw a pebble at a brick wall, it will bounce **off the wall**, once. No hard object will bounce on a plate like a ball. He is describing something moving up and down on the plate **more than once**. He even says: jumping **up and down**.

Comment: @Lambie: Actually, hard objects bounce _better_ than softer ones, because they deform less upon impact, and, thus, lose less energy per bounce.

Comment: @Vikki Hard objects thrown against a hard object will bounce only once, if at all; **One Bounce**. You cannot throw a hard object at a plate and have it bounce like a rubber ball. For some reason, no one seems interested in the basic idea of jiggling. Too bad.

Comment: @Lambie: Hard objects will bounce over and over again until their kinetic energy is dissipated, just like soft ones do.  What makes you think they wouldn't?

Comment: In my explanation, I said: You cannot bounce hard objects **on a hard object**. A stone (small) will not bounce on a plate (a ceramic stone plate). A rubber ball will. Come on.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the objects are, the thing they're located in, and how many times it is done.

If it happens multiple times, you might be **bouncing** the objects:

> [Merriam-Webster, from [*bounce*]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bounce)
> *transitive*
> 2 : to cause to rebound or be reflected
>     // bounce a ball
>     // bounce a light ray off a reflector
>
> *intransitive*
> 1 : to rebound or reflect after striking a surface (such as the ground)

> // He was *bouncing* a tennis ball against the garage door.
> // *bouncing* the ball back and forth

In this example in the sentence, *in* is not the correct preposition. There are two others you can use:

- I am *bouncing* the objects ***on*** the plate.
- I am *bouncing* the objects ***against*** the plate.

It depends if you want to emphasize where the objects are (*on*) or what they are rebounding from (*against*).

---

But if it's dice on a plate, and you do it only once, then you would say the following:

> I am **rolling** the dice *on* the plate.

---

If what you're describing is cooking, then you would use a different verb and prepositions, and it would be somewhat contextual.

- I am **flipping** eggs [*with* a frying pan].
- I am **flipping** pancakes [*with* a frying pan].

*but*

- I am **tossing** salad [*in* a bowl].

Generally, you *flip* things *with* a frying pan, but you *toss* things *in* a bowl.

Comment: "I am rolling the dice on the plate."==> does it mean "I have to make the dice jump once"?

Comment: @Tom You do not have to make the dice jump in order to roll them. Also, the act of bouncing isn't necessarily exclusive of them being rolled. In casinos, dice are *rolled* on a table, after which time they often bounce against the table several times before coming to rest. The tricky part of this question is that there are many different possible scenarios, and there isn't a single verb for all of them—or even a single verb for some of them.

Comment: I've always used *bounce* for that

Comment: @Wistful Yes. I disagree with the other answer that you can't bounce hard objects off of other hard objects. If you throw a rock at a wall, it will *bounce* off, falling back and down. And falling rocks will *bounce* off of cliff faces. The same is true of rocks and frying pans. It wouldn't make for the best of experiences (it seems like an odd thing to think of doing), but the two objects would still contact each other, after which the rocks would bounce away.

Comment: Rocks do not "jump up and down" off a wall. They would bounce just once and fall on the ground.

Comment: @Lambie Rocks don't "jump" at all. If we take the phrasing of the question literally, then none of the synonymous answers will work. As a teenager I used to spend long periods of time at recess *bouncing* pebbles off of the brick wall of my school, to see which I could make come back the farthest. The activity I was engaged in was *bouncing pebbles*. I also *did* spend some time engaged in just the kind of bouncing activity described in this question—continuous bouncing of the same thing—and quickly discovered it wasn't as effective. But that didn't change the word I would use to describe it.

Comment: Of course, they don't "jump". That is the OP's way, however,of describing it, inaccurately, Of course, you bounce a pebble **off the wall**, but it does not keep going. It hits the wall, bounces off and falls. I wonder why  you are such sour grapes....bouncing balls could be in a lotto machine. But not on a plate.

Comment: @Lambie Paddle ball is nothing other than, essentially, a ball attached to a rubber string, which is then attached to a plate-like piece of wood. Replace the ball with a rock and nobody would buy it, because it wouldn't work well, but it's *possible* to still have it function in a poor fashion if you hit the rock strongly enough. Especially if you hit the rock up into the air, wait for it to fall down, and then repeat. The rock still bounces off the plate-like paddle, and if you do it right, you can have the process repeat more than once: you'll be bouncing the same rock repeatedly.

Comment: Jason, I think you are annoyed because none of the terms really work, including jiggle. The description is flawed. Why you insist that one can bounce objects up and down on a plate, I just don't understand...let's leave it. The OP's thing is objects **on a plate**.

Comment: @Lambie I'm not annoyed at all—I'm actually grinning to myself as I have this debate. I'd like to see other answers with other verbs that could be used. I appreciate the different input that's being given to a situation that doesn't seem to have much practical real-world application. (I can't really imagine anybody doing exactly what the question describes in the first place.) Your use of *jiggle* is just as valid as my use of *bounce*, both used to describe different aspects of the same activity shown in the picture in the question.